# Provider Host App- App Domain

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I am new to Provider Hosted App developement. I am planning to create a provider host app and while I was reading many articles , I got confused some terminologies like App-domain and Forward lookup zone, blah blah... Kindly help me here

"So for Provider hosted Apps, it better to create a new App domain" What does this mean? Is this talking about a new DNS record or a  new zone or an entirely new DNS domain. Please help me here. thanks

Comment: This link will give you better idea to configure an environment for apps for SharePoint - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx